# C# - Problema al realizar una condicion (IF) correctamente sobre celdas de un DataGridView

Tags: c#, visual-studio, condiciones

Estoy haciendo un programa tipo *checador* en el que tengo una tabla en un `DataGridView` y escaneo con un lector de código de barras para llenar un `TextBox`, cuando detecta algún código que coincide con lo que se ha insertado aumenta en ***1*** el valor en la columna *Capturado* y limpia el `TextBox` para poder hacerlo de nuevo, todo esto funciona correctamente.

El problema viene cuando quiero aplicar una condición, para que si se ingresa un código cuyo valor en la columna *Capturado* es igual a la columna *Solicitado* **(entiéndase que ya se capturaron todas las unidades necesarias y no se necesitan mas)** ya no ingrese a la parte donde aumenta el contador y solo muestre un mensaje en pantalla con el texto `Unidades Completas`, pero no importa como organice el `if` siempre entra a la condición aunque en teoría no la cumple, aumenta el contador y muestra el mensaje.

Dejo el código de mi función a continuación:

```
if (e.KeyChar==Convert.ToChar(Keys.Enter))
        {


            foreach (DataGridViewRow fila in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                int b = Convert.ToInt32(fila.Cells[2].Value);
                int c = Convert.ToInt32(fila.Cells[3].Value);

                if (fila.Cells[2].Value == fila.Cells[3].Value)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("UNIDADES COMPLETAS");
                }

                else
                {
                    String a = null;
                    a = Convert.ToString(fila.Cells[0].Value);
                    if (a == txtCodigo.Text)
                    {
                        int n = Convert.ToInt32(fila.Cells[3].Value);
                        n = n + 1;
                        fila.Cells[3].Value = n;
                    }
                }
            }

            txtCodigo.Text = null;
        }
```

Los `Int` que están declarados los ocupe en un intento de cambiar la forma de hacer el `if` pero el resultado es el mismo, a continuación muestro la tabla inicial.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y lo que sucede cuando ingreso cualquier código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entiendo que es un error en mi `if` pero sinceramente no entiendo el comportamiento, espero alguien me pueda orientar, muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: y como primer paso, se te ocurrio mostrar por pantalla los valores de fila.Cells[2].Value y fila.Cells[3].Value en un message box, para ver cual es el valor que dice que es el mismo?

Comment: @gbianchi lo acabo de hacer y lo que hace es mostrarme uno a uno los valores de las celdas , de esta forma 10 0 ,6 0 , 8 0, 3 0, 9 0, y al final lo que veo que esta haciendo es pasarse a la fila nueva que no tiene nada , saca un 0 0 y entiendo por eso es el error, pero como reformulo la condicion?

Comment: o pones que la grilla no tenga una fila nueva automaticamente (te interesa eso?) o contas las filas antes.. y cuando estes en la ultima, no la tomes en cuenta.. igual fijate que el valor no es cero.. es nulo.. o nada..

Comment: Lo de agregar filas en automatico lo tengo por que jalo la tabla de un excel y dependiendo del excel es el tamaño de la tabla, y al final si es un null pero como hago una conversion para la comparacion convierte el null a 0, creo que lo mas sencillo sera poner una doble condicion agregando que sea diferente a null antes de convertir

Comment: es una solucion. Pero si vos no vas a agregar datos nuevos a mano a esta grilla, para que queres que acepte filas nuevas? ahi tenes un concepto equivocado. Esa propiedad es para agregar filas nuevas desde la pantalla, no desde donde vienen originalmente

Comment: Quieres que te indique el mensaje de completo, cuando el codigo ingresado haya haya justificado lo solicitado, y capturado vaya incrementando cada vez que se ingrese el mismo codigo? hasta que se gual a lo solicitado??

Comment: @gbianchi gracias , problema resuelto con eso, no sabia que eso solo aplicaba para ingresar cosas en pantalla, alguna vez desactive la opcion de agrecar columnas nuevas y el programa se colgaba por que no podia ingresar el excel, supuse que era lo mismo, si lo pones como respuesta para que la marque como resuelta, muchas gracias :)

Comment: despreocupate.. no es que puedan ahondar mucho como respuesta.. con el comentario alcanzaba.. en realidad lo resolviste solo con los tips que te fui dando ;) podes responderla vos mismo si queres. Pero tiene que ser una respuesta completa...